# Get DOM Reference of a SAPUI5 View/Control

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow, sapui5

I want show the info window for google maps. But the data or view is a ui5 view as below,

```
var oView = sap.ui.view({
  type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
  viewName :"com.example.view.ListView"                
});
```

And this view is perfect.

Mainly I have the google info window and I need to place this inside that info window as follows,

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: view, //Here I am getting below error
  position: coordinate
 });
infowindow.open(map);
```

So i am getting

**InvalidValueError: setContent: not a string; and Element-**

In this I know I can place a domNode or string inside the google info window's content. So I need to know how can we convert this ui5 view to domNode or any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DOM Node of a SAPUI5 View or Control by using the method [getDomRef](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getDomRef)

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: view.getDomRef(),
  position : coordinate
});
infowindow.open(map);
```

Please be aware that a SAPUI5 View/Control only has a DOM Reference after it was first rendered. Furthermore after a potential rerendering you might have to re-apply the above code.

BR Chris

Comment: Thanks man but i want to get that before rendering somewhere on the screen.

Comment: well, you can't attach it to a sapui5 control before rendering. Why does it have to be there before rendering? You could attach it to a dom node that exists before in your plain html and position that absolutely :/ Doesn't sound like the way to go though.